# Is it possible to write a web server in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I wonder if it's technically possible to write a simple web server in LLVM IR.

I've found one which is written in amd64 assembly and it's really working.

Comment: Since clang compiles c and c++ to llvm ir, and one can write a webserver in those two languages, yes, you could write one in llvm ir.

Comment: Yes, because you can write anything in IR. No, because you need a runtime library to do networking, and IR died not provide one. Either way, this question is off-topic, I'm afraid.

Comment: I want it to be directly written in LLVM IR for the same reason somebody has written one directly in assmebly.